# How can I disable all buttons and links on my page, but still let the postback occur?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, user-interface, dhtml

I'm trying to prevent the user from clicking on more than one postback-causing element on the page.  In other words, if they click the 'continue' submit button, they shouldn't be able to cause another postback before the original request comes back.

I've had a go with two versions of jQuery code. Neither does exactly what I want:

This version will disable all the postback elements, but in doing so, it stops the clicked element from firing.  For the record, I don't think the `.removeAttr('onclick')` is really required, but leaving it out doesn't seem to change the behaviour.

```
$(function() {
    $('a, :button, :submit').click(function() {
        var elements = $('a, :button, :submit');
        elements.attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeAttr('onclick');
    });
});
```

This version disables all **other** postback elements, but it lets me reuse the same element that was clicked - I don't want to be able to hit the same button twice.

```
$(function() {
    $('a, :button, :submit').click(function() {
        var otherelements = $('a:not(#' + $(this).attr('id') + '), :button:not(#' + $(this).attr('id') + '), :submit:not(#' + $(this).attr('id') + ')');
        elements.attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeAttr('onclick');
    });
});
```

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: I'm confused on your second approach... some typo?

Comment: No, no typo - it's just a (probably inefficient) way of getting all anchors, buttons, and submit buttons except for the one that's been triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a final version that worked - just overriding the form submit event rather than looking at any individual elements.

```
var submitted = false;
$(function() {
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
        if (!submitted) {
            submitted = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your first approach without JQuery, and it worked fine, i.e. disabling the submit button didn't prevent the form submission.

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="text" name="textfield" value="a" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true">
</form>
```

Maybe you want to double check is there is anything else, e.g. JQuery, going on?

Comment: I was a bit confused by that as well.  The trouble is, if I remove the jQuery above, everything works (but I can do a double postback).

I'm wondering if setting a disabled attribute is screwing with what happens server-side?

Comment: I don't think so. If all you want is to make sure the user doesn't accidentally do a double submit, you could simply do a (semi-)transparent layer over the whole page, with appropriate z-index and position css attributes.

Comment: I guess another thing you could try is to disable the elements at the onsubmit event.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could put a flag or something that it could remember what button it was clicked and if that flag exist, you can remove the onclick event on that postback-causing element.  But I think this cannot be done in client side scripting alone, since once the page is submitted, all client side elements and scripts are refreshed.

Comment: I've tried this suggestion and it seems to be working so far... I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of making this a click function make it onmouseup so it fires after the click event has occured.

Comment: interesting... I'll give it a try.  The only problem with that could be triggering a submit using the enter key.